# URL in email body is being checked before email is sent

Tags: php, email, smtp, verification

I am having an issue trying to create an email verification link. I add the lin k in the body of the email, and when that url is visited, it verifies the emial using the parameters in the url. However, when the email is sent, it visits that link automatically, and verifies it. Does anyone know why it does this, or what I am doing wrong?

Here's my code

```
$to = $_POST['email'];
$subject = "";
$headers = "From: email@example.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: email@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message = "<html><body><p>Here's a message</p>";
$message .= '<a href="http://www.example.com/verification.php?mv6e='.$encode.'&cv6v='.$verification.'">Click here to verify your application</a></body></html>';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

This should set a field in a database to "Verified". However, when the email is sent, the field is set to "Verified" before the user can even click on the link. Which gives me the impression that something is visiting the link beforehand. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to do some basic debugging, send it to a non existent email address on your domain, send it to a gmail account, etc etc.  Are you sure the entry in your database is being set etc.

Comment: Sure the link gets requested when _sending_ the message, not when receiving? This could be a head request by some virus detection thingy or similar. Certainly mail sending routines are not interested in the messages content. Also some email service providers are known to sniff messages sent through them. Especially some US American providers... It's against terrorism, you know?

Comment: You might want to check your web server logs to find the remote IP that is hitting your URL.  Then do a reverse lookup or a whois on this IP, and that might shed some light on what network the host is on that is hitting your URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a spam filter that checks the links in all emails. For example, gmail scans all emails for links to malicious websites.

You can add a [recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) to the verification page to make sure it is visited by a human, not some spam filtering bot.

Comment: Oh, yeah, people will be delighted when they have to use those annoying captchas just to verify that they received a message... :-)

Comment: Google tried to make them less annoying, just look on the page I linked to. Only one click is required now, no need to type text.

Comment: Oh, so google finished their OCR program? The internet users decoded all the bad quality scans they produce in libraries in their google books project and translated them for free? Cause this was why google created their captcha version :-)

Comment: They *said* that only one click is required now but I still always have to type text :D

Comment: So you are a robot! Ha! Gotcha!

Comment: Okay you've got me there. I'm a robot. But I'm a very good robot ^^

Comment: May we call you Marvin?